# BIND to PowerDNS migration: duplicate DNS suffix

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, powerdns

Using [this manual](https://doc.powerdns.com/authoritative/migration.html) for migration. But after in PowerDNS I see this:

```
PS C:\Users\ruslan> nslookup -type=ns domain.ru vs-powerdns01.domain.ru  
Address:  10.100.20.110

domain.ru.domain.ru  nameserver = ns2.domain.ru
ns2.domain.ru      internet address = correct IP address
ns1.domain.ru    internet address = correct IP address
```

In database table there is this entry:

```
17781 | 54 | domain.ru.domain.ru | SOA | ns2.domain.ru root.ns2.domain.ru  2010110096 28800 7200 604800 86400
```

The suffix is duplicated. I migrated another zones same method and result is corrected. Problem zone is the biggest zone. Where is can be mistake?

Comment: "Where is can be mistake?" You were missing a final dot at some point. If a name has no dot at the end, it is relative, and hence the actual current zone will be appended to it. `foobar.example.com.` in zone `example.com.` is indeed `foobar.example.com.` but `foobar.example.com` (no trailing dot) is in fact `foobar.example.com.example.com.`. So depending on your input you may have hit that case.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek The dot of "@ORIGIN" is not missing. I tried with the dot and without it. The same result... :-(